# Move files and prepend filename

Tags: bash

I am having difficulty moving files and prepending to the files with Bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
CAT="WFS_CAT"

for FILENAME in /foo/bar/20*
do
    mv "${FILENAME##*/}" "${CAT}.${FILENAME##*/}"
done;
```

The command errors out. It tries to move the full directory name and prepend to that instead of the individual files.

Comment: You should learn to identify the real problem and ask / google for that. Your real problem is, that in the FILENAME variable the whole path is stored, like you've already found out. What would be the solution? You only want the filename without the path, right? Google that, you'll find a solution in no time.

Comment: Well, if you want to move them within the same directory, you need to save and prepend the original directory before `"${CAT.}..."`. `${FILENAME##*/}` strips the directory, so when `mv` attempts to locate the file, it can't. Why not `srcdir=/foo/bar` then `for filename in "$srcdir/20"*; do mv "$filename" "$srcdir/${CAT}${filename##*/}"; done`?

Comment: what's up with this ## in the file name?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it should be much simpler to change the directory to the one your files are located in, as your `move` command only renames files in this directory. Do you mind trying this?

```
pushd /foo/bar

for FILENAME in 20*; do
    echo mv "${FILENAME}" "${CAT}.${FILENAME}"
done;

popd
```

Comment: Are you talking about "cd" into the directory before you run the for command?

Comment: Yes, that's the `pushd`  and `popd` in the snippet above. Works equally well with `cd /foo/bar` and `cd -`